# Checkbox checked status

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using MaterialUI components and i map through an array of object to generate some checkboxes as shown below.

```
const wrapper = () => {
    ...
    return(
        <FormGroup>
            {Object.keys(products).map((key) => {
                return <FormControlLabel label={products[key].name} key={key} control={
                    <CheckBox value={products[key].name} />
                }
            })
    );
}
```

So given the code above. Let's say the products array has 3 object. Whenever i check a checkbox, i want all others to get a checked false and the one i checked a check true.

I'm using the state Hook so the code above is a functional component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [Material-UI Checkbox Component](https://material-ui.com/components/checkboxes/#checkboxes) takes a prop `checked` of boolean type.

What you can do is maintain the flag for each checkbox and whenever any checkbox if pressed, just make its value in state true, and false the other and pass that state checked prop of each checkbox.

---

**BTW, the behavior you want to achieve here is not done by checkboxes, it is the behavior of [Radio Button](https://material-ui.com/components/radio-buttons/), where the user can select only one option at a time while checkboxes are used for multiple selections.**

(I believe [material-ui checkbox documentation](https://material-ui.com/components/checkboxes/#checkboxes) has a very clear explanation on this, Let me know if you can keep up by yourself or you want sample code too.)

Comment: Yes i ended up with the radio buttons. I don't know why i didn't go that way in the first place. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Radio buttons instead of checkBoxes in this case.
https://material-ui.com/components/radio-buttons/

No more than one radio button can be selected at a time which is what you are describing.